# ArgumentError in #new, Subclassing Enumerator

Tags: ruby, enumerator

I'm subclassing `Enumerator` like this:

```
class CuadraticPrimeGenerator < Enumerator
  def initialize(a=1,b=49)
    super do |y|
      x = 1
      loop do 
        y << x**2 + a*x + b
        x += 1
      end
    end
  end
end
```

However...

```
> CuadraticPrimeGenerator.new(1,49)
0027.rb:41:in `initialize': 49 is not a symbol (TypeError)
    from 0027.rb:41:in `initialize'
    from 0027.rb:48:in `new'
    from 0027.rb:48:in `<main>'
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about:

```
class CuadraticPrimeGenerator < Enumerator
  def initialize(a=1,b=49)
    super() do |y|
      count, x = 0, 1
      loop { y.yield(x**2 + a*x + b) }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: The reason is the default Enumerator class doesn't take in 2 parameters. Therefore, when you called super without parentheses, ruby will assume that you want to pass in whatever parameters from the child class. Therefore, you must specifically use parentheses to tell ruby otherwise.