# How do I wrap an array with a specific subclass of Enumerator?

Tags: ruby, enumerable, enumerator

I've created a subclass of Enumerator with a few special properties (i.e. it knows its elements are Time objects):

```
class TimedEnumerator < Enumerator
  ...some time-specific methods...
end
```

Given an array of Time objects, how do I generate a TimedEnumerator?  My first thought was simply to use the ::new method, but that generates a deprecation warning:

```
>> TimedEnumerator.new(array)
(irb):12: warning: Enumerator.new without a block is deprecated; use Object#to_enum
```

And of course, `array.to_enum` creates an Enumerator object, not a TimedEnumerator object.

What's the right way to do this?

Comment: In general, I would avoid this entirely, as you would need to override a core `Object` method. I think an easier way to do this is to wrap an enumerator in a decorator class that implements your time-specific methods but still delegates back to the enumerator for the standard behavior.

Comment: @ZachKemp: by "avoid this entirely", I assume you mean modify .to_enum?  I agree.  Not sure what you mean by the "easier way".  Got an example?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to subclass Enumerator doing this:

```
class TimedEnumerator < Enumerator
  def initialize(array)
    super() do |array|
      #your logic
    end
  end 
end

TimedEnumerator.new(array)
#=> <TimedEnumerator: #<Enumerator::Generator:0x007ff4cb89a9f0>:each>
```

Found the `super()` trick from here: [ArgumentError in #new, Subclassing Enumerator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16016995/argumenterror-in-new-subclassing-enumerator).

Comment: Mind you, all I want is to do the equivalent of `TimedEnumerator.new(array)` but without the deprecation warning.  I'm not trying to act on the array in the .new method, I just want it wrapped in my subclass of Enumerator.